# How to call setinterval in one function and settimeout in another function in javascript or refresh a div onclick ajax is calling the multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is my HTML code !

```
<body onload="fun1()">
<ul id="nav" class="nav" style="font-size:12px;">
<li><a href="#" id="m_blink" onclick="fun1()">Tab1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="d_blink" onclick="fun2()">Tab2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" id="k_blink" onclick="fun3()">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
<div id='home'></div>
```

This is my javascript functions calling  and loading pages in HOME div, the pages are loading properly, but i want to refresh the particular HOME div for every 5 seconds using setInterval and setTimeout   or is there any other way, please let me know.

```
function fun1(){

    $("#home").load("tab1.php",{},function(){});
}


function fun2(){

        $("#home").load("tab2.php",{},function(){});
}

function fun3(){

        $("#home").load("tab3.php",{},function(){});
}
```

And make sure the onload page is loading fun1()